# Raphaeljs - making a box cover a line

Tags: javascript, svg, opacity

The following webpage will draw a box with a line through it (using http://raphaeljs.com)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    paper = Raphael("paper1", 100, 100);
    paper.rect(40, 40, 20, 20);
    paper.path("M50,10L50,90");
}
</script>

<div id="paper1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the box to cover the line. I've tried applying every combination of opaque, fill-opacity and stroke-opacity and done a silly number of searches (Google, this site, etc). Nothing works.

Comment: So you just need to swap the order of the rect and path creation then unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I've tried swapping the order (and double checked by swapping the order in my example) - no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want I think. The rect must be filled so its contents are opaque.

```
paper = Raphael("paper1", 100, 100);
paper.path("M50,10L50,90");
var rect = paper.rect(40, 40, 20, 20);
rect.attr({fill: "white"});
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was adding rectangles after paths, but I really wasn't because of the way my loops were nested. Your feedback helped me look at my code with new eyes.